# Why gmail upload progress bar goes fast at the very end?

Tags: progress-bar, gmail

If I am upload 20 MB File on gmail, on progress bar it will take some time to upload & at very last seconds, the progress bar goes fast.

Why so?

Comment: For questions about why Company X made a certain design decision, we can't really give a correct answer. We can only speculate. You would need to contact that company themselves (find an official support forum for instance) as we'll just be making subjective opinions.

Answer (score 1):

Progress bars are actually [very difficult to predict](http://www.howtogeek.com/139118/htg-explains-why-are-progress-bars-generally-inaccurate/).

In short:

> Past Results Do Not Guarantee Future Performance

People tend to strongly rely on the first estimation provided by the progress bar - this is a cognitive bias called [anchoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anchoring).

**Getting a pessimistic estimation is one way to manage users' expectations.**

When the file is completed and the progress bar is still running, they provide you this feedback to give an impression of speed.

---

Another way of seeing it, is to think about gmail as a good friend. When you give him a task to do that is difficult to estimate, he will try to give you a rounded up one. He finishes early or on time, you think good of him; not if he is late.

Comment: Because people didn't understood that an estimate is no guarantee Microsoft got rid of it inside the file action dialog of Windows 8 and Windos 10. Now you can only see current speed and overall progress but no estimate is made